# How to calculate big exponents (with modular division involved)?

Tags: exponentiation

I found the following equation online when working with cryptography.

`1702^2732 x 2083^2526 = 704 mod 3119`

Now I'd like to understand the math behind:

- how do we calculate exponentiation with number that high?
- how did we get this `mod` part?

From the article, it looks like the calculation has been done by hand, with no computer involved.

Comment: Use the chinese remainder theorem and eulers totient functoin

Comment: http://www.mathwarehouse.com/arithmetic/numbers/prime-number/prime-factorization.php?number=3119. So, we cannot avoid calculations